# Can't cast UITableViewCells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm not able to cast my UITableViewCells to my custom class. I have a BaseCell class which extends UITableViewCell, and then a ProfilePictureCell class which extends BaseCell. I'm trying to cast in cellForRowAtIndexPath like so:

```
    if row == kProfilePictureRow {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kProfilePicIdentifier) as? ProfilePictureTableViewCell
    }
```

But, this only ever makes cell a UITableViewCell class. I've tried registering the class and the nib for it, both to no avail. I've got the identifier set in my storyboard, I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Why can't I do something as simple as casting to a different tableView cell subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have declare upside, but here is the working example of Custom `UITableViewCell`.

First of all, take the variable as your Custom `UITableViewCell`

```
var cell: CustomTableViewCell?
```

and then you can deque using the identifier as below:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("your_identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell
```

Hope, it helps!

Answer (score -1):

maybe the problem is because you are using `as?` try to use `as!` not `as?`

also the cell shouldn't be `Optional` because `func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` must returns `UITableView`